# OneSignal notifications to users having email id

Tags: onesignal

I have a OneSignal notifications integrated to my Web Application it works fine,but the problem is I need to send notification only to a specific user. I will select a email and send the notification. For that `OneSignal` provides segment,when I create a segment and give a email ID it says 0 users in the segment.

My question how is the email ID I type in the segment gets compared with and return me 0 users?

Answer (score 1):

Use tag instead. For the person you want to send the message to, set a tag, for example: {email: jimmy@jimmy.com}.

And then in your notification sending code, send to the person based on tag. e.g.

```
    $content = array(
        "en" => "hello jimmy"
        );

    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => <your_ID_here> ,
        'filters' => array(array("field" => "tag", "key" => "email", "relation" => "=", "value" => "jimmy@jimmy.com")),
        'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
        'contents' => $content
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8','Authorization: Basic '.$_SESSION['global_rest_id']));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```